# elisp debugging and elc files

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have installed the *persp-mode* and *workspaces* packages from the elpa repository. *persp-mode* depends on *workspaces*.

I was unable to get *persp-mode* working until the `workspace.elc` file was deleted. I have made a backup of this file for troubleshooting.

- What could have been the cause of error?
- How can I debug this problem systematically?

Comment: Is everything working now without the *.elc files (i.e., just the *.el files) for both packages?  If so, then just `M-x byte-compile` new *.elc files.

Comment: If you continue getting error messages after you've recompiled the file, please tell us what the error message is.

Comment: @ChrisBarrett:Its fine after recompiling the workspace.el file. So it seems the workspace.elc file was not compiled properly. The binary files of working and non-working workspace.elc files differ. How could have this problem be systematically debugged.

Comment: @lawlist: The problem was only with the workspace.elc file and i did not change anything related to perp-mode to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Without you giving us the error message it's hard to know what caused this, but generally the easiest way to debug compilation issues is to restart Emacs (so you have a fresh image), go back to the source file and recompile it with `M-x emacs-lisp-byte-compile-and-load`. This will show you any errors or warnings that occur when the file is compiled. Look for the following:

- undefined variables and functions, which often indicate

  - features that have not been required by the package
  - simple typing errors
- `unexpected end of input` errors, which indicate unbalanced parens
- general usage errors, such as

  - function calls with incorrect argument counts
  - macro expansion errors

These sorts of issues are usually pretty easy to fix. Remember, you can always redefine the package's functions and vars yourself if they are broken.